# Can't connect via FTP or SFTP to CentOS 8 server running vsftpd

Tags: vsftpd, centos8

I followed the guide to installing vsftp here https://www.tecmint.com/install-ftp-server-in-rhel-8/

The daemon is running:

```
# systemctl status vsftpd
● vsftpd.service - Vsftpd ftp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-22 12:33:32 UTC; 5s ago
  Process: 11345 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11346 (vsftpd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 26213)
   Memory: 724.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/vsftpd.service

           └─11346 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

I have enable the SeLinux security boolean to allow ftpd_full_access

```
    # sudo getsebool -a | grep ftpd_full_access
    ftpd_full_access --> on
```

I have a trusted zone that is only accessible from our ofice VPN IP address and these are the rules and services associated with it:

```
 # firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=trusted
trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: <my office vpn ip address>
  services: ftp mysql ssh
  ports: 21/tcp 45073/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

My /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf conf looks like this:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
lock_upload_files=YES
```

But I can't connect from Filezilla on my desktop machine which is using the VPN IP address.

```
Status: Connecting to nn.nn.nn.nn... 
Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=9 
Command: open "nick.weavers@nn.nn.nn.nn" 22 
Command: Pass: ************ 
Status: Connected to nn.nn.nn.nn 
Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity 
Error: Could not connect to server
```

I can connect to the same server to get an ssh session.

I must be missing something, but I can't see what. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: ```Status: Connecting to nn.nn.nn.nn...
Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=9
Command: open "nick.weavers@nn.nn.nn.nn" 22
Command: Pass: ************
Status: Connected to nn.nn.nn.nn
Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error: Could not connect to server```